# Problem with Twitter Mobile linking

Tags: twitter

I am trying to add my mobile phone number to my Twitter ID, but a dialog box appears with the following message:

[image]

But there is no account with my phone number and Twitter itself shows the same:

[image]

Comment: So what’s your question?

Comment: My question is that how should I get rid of the issue, please help if possible, because if at all it gets locked, I won’t be able to unlock it as well as I will be unable to create a new one